# Dynamic div bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html, size

I have three divs: head, foot and textbox. 
The head and foot divs are fixed positions, and the third div is partly fixed (margin-top).

My question is: How can I change the textbox's div bottom to fix different monitors size? I can't use 100% height because it hangs on foot div. In this homepage I don't use scrollbar, because the backgrounk is changing image files. I woud like to make it somehow the margin-bottom part keep distance the monitor's bottom.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Div bottom</title>
<style>
.head{
    position:absolute;
    clear:both;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.foot {
    position:fixed;
    clear:both;
    height:35px;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
    bottom:0px;
}
.textbox {     
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    background-color:red;
    z-index:0;
    text-align:justify;
    color:black;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top:100px;
    width:910px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="head">HEAD</div>

<div class="textbox">?</div>

<div class="foot">FOOT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to accomplish this .. add in the following script to your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=resize_height;

function resize_height(){
    var height=0;
    var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    if(self.innerHeight){
        height=self.innerHeight;
    }else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth){
        height=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }else if(document.body){
        height=document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    divs[1].style.height=(parseInt(height)-200)+'px';
}

</script>
```

The 200 comes from height and padding and margins, you could dynamically generate the 200 by taking the height/padding from your other divs and offsetting it to achieve what you want.

EDIT:

also, for textbox, remove margin-top:100px; and replace with top:100px; ....

```
.textbox {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:0;
    text-align:justify;
    color:black;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*margin-top:100px;*/
    width:910px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a script for that, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/MN4uE/2/) is a pure CSS solution for the 'header content footer' layout.

the margin between the sections is optional, so and so are the vertical & horizontal centering. and everything is totally responsive.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper Container Inverse">
            <div>
                <div class="Footer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper Content">
                    <div class="Centered">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.Inverse, .Inverse > *
{
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/*For Centering only*/
    .Content:before
    {    
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }
    .Centered
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }


/*For demonstration only*/
p
{    
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.Important
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
}

body > .Container
{
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Header, .Footer
{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.Header
{
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.Content
{
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
.Footer
{
    background-color: #b5a8b7;
}
```